# Page layout on custom metadata type

Tags: custom-metadata

I've seen that I can asign page layout to custom metadata by I don't know where it is used.

Is there a way to display custom metadata as if it were a standart object with a page layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is not added to the page layout when you want to create the records for the custom metadata by using manage record button then you will not be able to see that field in the layout.

[image]

Edit or create record page:

[image]